# Contesting a duplicate question: Being a Journal Reviewer

Tags: discussion

The following question is being considered to be a duplicate of the second.

[How do I become a journal reviewer?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1878/319)

[How do you earn opportunites to review journals or conference papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1498/319)

I was basing the first question on the second. I'm not doubting the opportunities to review papers as a grad student or a post-doc. However, I'm more curious about how one becomes the primary reviewer vs. being a person who helps out with the review. I'm curious about how to separate the two questions or potentially merge them.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for posting this here. I closed your question because it seemed to be completely answered by the [accepted answer of the first](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/1500/73). The question you posed above (primary vs. "helper" reviewer) here is definitely a different one, but I didn't see that in the question text, which is why I closed it. Why don't you just edit the question to reflect what you asked above and we can re-open it? *Note:* After you make the edit, add a comment with "@eykanal" so I'll be notified that the edit was made.

Comment: I reread your answer it does seem to sufficiently answer my question. Thanks.